# Verifying RSA signature from Google Licencing with PyCrypto

Tags: android, python, rsa

I am build a Python implementation of the verification of the [Google License signature](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html). 
I am having problem importing the public RSA key into the python module.

The key is a 2048-bit RSA and the public part of this key you get from the developer console on Google Play. It is "base64 encoded".

When I try to load it with the following Python code

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG.."
pubkey = RSA.importKey(BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY)
```

I get the error `ValueError: RSA key format is not supported`

I get the same error when I add base64 decoding.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import base64
BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG.."
pubkey = RSA.importKey(base64.b64decode(BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY))
```

Checking the standard implementation of how the key is loaded in Android it is base64 decoded and then sent to a class called [X509EncodedKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html). The constructor to this class takes one argument

```
encodedKey - the key, which is assumed to be encoded according to the X.509 standard. The contents of the array are copied to protect against subsequent modification.
```

Thus my guess is that the key is X.509 encoded and then base64 endoded. However, the `importKey` function in the RSA module [claims](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html#importKey) to support this encoding

```
X.509 subjectPublicKeyInfo DER SEQUENCE (binary or PEM encoding)
```

Comment: I interpret the docs the same way, namely what you're doing should work. Therefore perhaps your public key is not quite what you think it is. [Here](http://lapo.it/asn1js/) is a website I often use to check the ASN.1 structure of suspect data.

Comment: @GregS, just discovered that the key had been corrupted. The above steps worked just fine when I fixed the key. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My key was corrupted and the above approach worked just fine, as noted by @GregS.

Answer (score 0):

Your symptom that base 64 encoded values being supported out of the box by the x509 code you provided is probably not true.

X.509 subjectPublicKeyInfo DER SEQUENCE (binary or PEM encoding)

Directly stated binary or pem encoding.  You actually have to decode the base 64 encoded string, and then figure out what to do from their ( I'm not sure what output the decoding will produce in relation to X509 code)